# How to avoid caching of routes with DHH's monkey patch about distributing routes in multiple files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm using Rails 3.1 and DHH's monkey patch about distributing routes in multiple files:

https://gist.github.com/2492118

So when I change routes in one of the routes of the routes directory I have to deactivate a routes sub file like config/routes/users.rb:

```
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  #draw :users
end
```

Request a page and activate the routes sub file.

```
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  draw :users
end
```

After I request a page I can finally see the new user route changes.

Does anyone know a solution on how to avoid this workaround and see the change in route sub files immediately?